# RememberSaveable restore value type influenced by the order of the code?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple complete Composable Code below (which you can put in your MainActivity.kt verbatim and run it)

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            var number by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
            MyComposableFun("$number")

            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                while(true) {
                    delay(500)
                    number++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyComposableFun(textValue: String) {

    var myText by rememberSaveable(textValue) { mutableStateOf(textValue) }
    var checkedState by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Row (verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Checkbox(
            checked = checkedState,
            onCheckedChange = {
                myText = if (it) "Internal Change" else "Internal Change Again"
                checkedState = it
            }
        )
        Text("Title: $myText")
    }
}
```

When I run it, it will just auto increment the number.
If I put it in the background (and kill the process, using "Don't Keep Activity" setting), and put it back in the foreground, it will try to restore the state. At that time it will crash with

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
        at com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.MainActivityKt.MyComposableFun$lambda-3(MainActivity.kt:109)
        at com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.MainActivityKt.MyComposableFun(MainActivity.kt:42)
        at com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:20)
```

complaining wrong casting in the line of `checked = checkedState,` in

```
        Checkbox(
            checked = checkedState,
            onCheckedChange = {
                myText = if (it) "Internal Change" else "Internal Change Again"
                checkedState = it
            }
        )
```

To fix this issue, I just need to swap the

```
    var myText by rememberSaveable(textValue) { mutableStateOf(textValue) }
    var checkedState by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

to

```
    var checkedState by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var myText by rememberSaveable(textValue) { mutableStateOf(textValue) }
```

It looks like the rememberSaveable value is restoration is done incorrectly, and influenced by the order of the code (which is odd). Feels like a bug in Google Jetpack Compose code, but ask here in case I miss anything obvious

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was because I'm using Compose version 1.1.1.
It has been fixed in compose version 1.2.0